# Tor not working in Chromium after update to Ubuntu 23.04 but works in Firefox

Tags: configuration, chromium, 23.04, tor

I run Tor headless on Ubuntu 23.04. I just updated from 22.10 to Ubuntu 23.04, and Tor stopped working in Chromium but works fine in Firefox. Launching http://check.torproject.org shows Tor not connected Chromium nor Google Chrome, but connected in Firefox. Appreciate any suggestions on how to diagnose and fix.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix [here](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2023/08/how-to-configure-tor-socks-proxy-on-debian-12-ubuntu-2204.html). To get Chromium and Google Chrome to connect to my computer proxy settings, I had to enable **tor systemctl**. See below. I opened terminal window  and then ran command:

> $ sudo systemctl enable --now tor

I then checked tor status to assure it was enabled with command:

> $ sudo systemctl status tor